# A predictable sequence

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, sequence

"Four, four, four, ..." droned the random number generating monster. "Are you sure that's random?" I asked. "That's the problem with randomness, you can never be sure!" he replied. But suddenly the long string of 4s was broken up by an 8, then later a 12, before he returned to his 4s.

Can you complete the following sequence? The answer is not random.

> 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ?

Comment: But 4 is a random number: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: indeed :) https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think the next number is

> 5  - giving the gaps between the years the modern Summer [Olympic Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Olympic_Games#List_of_Summer_Olympic_Games) took place.

The number sequence goes as

> steps of 4 from I Athens 1896 to V Stockholm 1912
>  gap of 8 to VII Antwerp 1920
>  steps of 4 to XI Berlin 1936
>  gap of 12 to XIV London 1948
>  steps of 4 to XXXI Rio de Janeiro 2016
>  gap of 5 to XXXII Tokyo which was held in 2021

Comment: Wow! I wonder how someone can even think in these lines to come up with such an awesome answer! No wonder you have such a reputation score!