# Another predictable sequence: 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 17, etc

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, sequence, time

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #6: Is it really that [time] again?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/monthly-topic-challenge-6-is-it-really-that-time-again?cb=1).</sub>

---

Can you find the pattern? Note: The next number hasn't been worked out yet.

```
1 1 2 2 1 17 11 13 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Another note: This sequence is part of the [fraternity crossword](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118564/#), linked from Clue 6×10<sup>1</sup>.

---

Hint 1:

> This sequence is generated in roughly the same way as [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111389/#), but is based on a different series of events.

Comment: I'm not sure if this puzzle fits the criteria of the challenge. The fact that all the currently-found terms are either [square](http://oeis.org/A000290#) or [prime](http://oeis.org/A000040#) doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: I think it fits perfectly - it's a question related to [tag:time]... That's all that's required :)

Comment: @Stiv I don't think it deserves the "time" tag, according to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sequence represents...

> ...the number of **years** (hence the [time](/questions/tagged/time) tag) served in each 'electoral term' by the [**Leader(s) of the Central Committee of the Chinese Communist Party**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_of_the_Chinese_Communist_Party).

The terms represent:

> 1 = Chen Duxiu (1921-22)
>  1 = Chen Duxiu (1922-23)
>  2 = Chen Duxiu (1923-25)
>  2 = Chen Duxiu (1925-27)
>  1 = Xiang Zhongfa (1927-28)
>  17 = Bo Gu/Zhang Wentian/Mao Zedong (1928-45)
>  11 = Mao Zedong (1945-56)
>  13 = Mao Zedong (1956-69)
>  4 = Mao Zedong (1969-73)
>  4 = Mao Zedong (1973-77)
>  5 = Hua Guofeng/Hu Yaobang (1977-82)
>  5 = Hu Yaobang/Zhao Ziyang (1982-87)
>  5 = Zhao Ziyang/Jiang Zemin (1987-92)
>  5 = Jiang Zemin (1992-97)
>  5 = Jiang Zemin (1997-2002)
>  5 = Hu Jintao (2002-07)
>  5 = Hu Jintao (2007-12)
>  5 = Xi Jinping (2012-17)
>  5 = Xi Jinping (2017-22)

The next term in the sequence is not yet known, because...

> ...Xi Jinping's current term as leader began in 2022 but is not yet completed.

Comment: Why most questions are more based on general knowledge than on puzzling ?

Comment: @An_Elephant I wouldn't say 'most' - take a look at some specific [tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags) to get a feel for what else is out there on the site. General knowledge is a legitimate element to a puzzle, but you definitely want variety...

Comment: No, I was seeing famous questions.

Comment: @Stiv Please add Wikipedia links, if possible. (Sorry for double-posting)

Comment: @Scratch---Cat There's already a Wikipedia link within the answer that links to all of the information required - do you not think that's enough? (Otherwise the answer will just end up full of excessive links...)

Comment: @Stiv I see... Thanks for reminding.